# How to insert from each row into to multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I'm pretty new to SQL Server (using ssms). I need some help to insert and organize data from one table into multiple tables (which are connected to each other by PK/FK).

The source table has the following columns:

```
Email, UserName, Phone
```

It's a messy table with lots of duplicates: same email with different username and so on..

My data tables are:

1. `Person` - PersonID(PK, int, not null)
2. `Email` - Email (nvarchar, null) , PersonID (FK, int, not null)
3. `Phone` - PhoneNumber (int, null) , PersonID (FK, int, not null)
4. `UserName` -  UserName (nvarchar, null) , PersonID (FK, int, not null)

For each row in the source table, I need to check if the person already exists (by Email); if it does exist, I need to add the new data (if any), else I need to create a new person and add the data.

I searched here for some solutions and find recommendations of using CURSOR.
I tried it, but it takes a really long time to execute (hours.. and still going)

Thanks for any help!

example:
from>

```
EMAIL | USERNAME | PHONE
------------------------
a@a.a | john | 956165
b@b.b | smith | 123456
c@c.c | bob | 654321
d@d.d | mike | 986514
a@a.a | dan | 658732
e@e.e | dave | 147258
f@f.f | harry | 951962
b@b.b | emmy | 456789
g@g.g | kelly | 789466
h@h.h | kelly | 258369
a@a.a | ana | 852369
```

to>

```
EMAIL | PERSONID
----------------
a@a.a | 1
b@b.b | 2
c@c.c | 3
d@d.d | 4
e@e.e | 5
f@f.f | 6
g@g.g | 7
h@h.h | 8

USERNAME | PERSONID
-------------------
john | 1
smith | 2
bob | 3
mike | 4
dan | 1
dave | 5
harry | 6
emmy | 2
kelly | 7
kelly | 8
ana | 1

PHONE | PERSONID
----------------
956165 | 1
123456 | 2
654321 | 3
986514 | 4
658732 | 1
147258 | 5
951962 | 6
456789 | 2
789466 | 7
258369 | 8
852369 | 1
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185526/discussion-on-question-by-r-tom-how-to-insert-from-each-row-into-to-multiple-tab).

Answer (score 0):

Cursors will generally be slower as they operate on a row-by-row basis.  Using set based operations, such as a join, will yield better performance.  It's somewhat older, but this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlprogrammability/2008/03/18/increase-your-sql-server-performance-by-replacing-cursors-with-set-operations/) further details the implications of cursors as opposed to set operations.  I wasn't entirely sure what columns you want to use to verify matches, as well as what data to add, but a basic example is below and you can fill in the columns as necessary.  The Email table was used in the example.  For the `UPDATE`, this will update existing rows based off corresponding rows in the source table.  Being an `INNER JOIN`, only rows with matches on both sides will be impacted.  In the second statement, this is an `INSERT` using only rows from the source table that don't exist in the Email table.  This same functionality could also be accomplished using the `MERGE` statement, however there are a number of issues with this, including problems with deadlocks and key violations.

**Update Existing Rows:**

```
UPDATE E
SET E.ColumnA = SRC.ColumnA,
E.ColumnB = SRC.ColumnB
FROM YourDatabase.YourSchema.Email E
INNER JOIN YourDatabase.YourSchema.SourceTable SRC
ON E.Email = SRC.Email
```

**Add New Rows:**

```
INSERT INTO YourDatabase.YourSchema.Email (ColumnA, ColumnB)
SELECT 
ColumnA, 
ColumnB
FROM YourDatabase.YourSchema.SourceTable 
WHERE EMAIL NOT IN ((SELECT EMAIL FROM YourDatabase.YourSchema.Email))
```